# Java applet - mouse and key listener

Tags: java, applet, events, listener

Is there a way to implement a KeyListener and MouseListener in the same applet? I already tried any ways I thought that would work and I tried Google. :\

my try:

```
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\DanJavaGen\tileGen.java:23: tileGen is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
public class tileGen extends JApplet implements KeyListener, MouseListener  {
       ^
1 error
```

Comment: Wait I forgot to add the Mouse Listeners... silly me. <_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly implement both KeyListener and MouseListener in the same applet :)

You must have the following methods in the tileGen class:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)b{
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}
```

If you already have some of these methods implemented you can leave them out.

Gentle hint: Capitalize your class name as TileGen :)  Lower-case class names are — by convention — used only for generated or internal code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm giving you a lot of rep, huh? Hehe I got another question. :P